# GCC local struct vs individual variables and PGO optimziation

Tags: c, gcc, struct

We are trying to refactor the interpreter loop SWI-Prolog.  That is a giant function using GCC's label addresses to refer to the virtual machine instructions.  This function has a number of VM register variables.  It turns out that it makes a difference whether one writes

```
PL_next_solution(qid_t qid)
{ type1 v1;
  type2 v2;
  // 13 in total

  // lots of code
}
```

or

```
PL_next_solution(qid_t qid)
{ struct
  { type1 v1;
    type2 v2;
    // 13 in total
  } registers;

  // lots of code
}
```

Without profile guided optimization the performance difference of the resulting program is small (<5%) while with PGO optimization the difference is about 20%.  This was rather unexpected.  Why does this happen?  Does gcc respect the memory layout of the structure despite the fact that it isn't known outside this function?

Comment: Difference in what?

Comment: Sorry, performance of the resulting program

Comment: Performance as in run time? Or memory consumption?

Comment: Runtime.   The function is not recursive, so the little storage of the automatic variables is irrelevant.   Most of these variables are pointers or integers.

Comment: Is the address of `registers` variable taken? and passed somewhere? `the difference is about 20%` erm, which one is faster?

Comment: I think more code is needed

Comment: Do any of the members of the `registers` struct have their address taken?  I'm not sure, but that might be sufficient to require that the entire struct be laid out in memory.

Comment: @NateEldredge: yes, you are right.    I tried getting the addresses of the plain local variable version to see whether smart variable reordering may be involved.   It looks like GCC is fairly simple here: smaller objects first and keep ordering of equal sized objects.    The effect of taking these addresses is equally bad on performance as using the struct.   Will work on this and report.

Comment: Yes.  Avoiding getting a pointer to any of the struct members makes the difference go away.   If you add the comment as an answer I'll mark it as answer.   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your further tests, it sounds like the performance hit comes from taking the address of one or more of the struct members and passing it to a function that the compiler can't see.  I believe that when you do this, the compiler has to assume that the entire struct has [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).  This inhibits many possible optimizations: it means that the struct has to be laid out in memory, and moreover that members have to be stored to and reloaded from that memory around every function call.

To see why, look at an example like this:

```
void foo(int *);
void bar(void);
struct qux { 
    int a,b,c;
    char huge[5000];
};
int fum(void) {
    struct qux s = { 1,2,3 };
    foo(&s.b);
    s.c=4;
    bar();
    return s.a+s.c;
}
```

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/M1or6Gfcs)

Notice that even with maximum optimization:

- the unused member `huge` is still allocated and initialized
- `s.c=4` involves a store to memory
- `s.a` and `s.c` are reloaded from memory after the call to `bar()`

I think the point is that for all the compiler knows, the functions `foo()` and `bar()` could be doing:

```
int *global_ptr;
void foo(int *ip) {
    struct qux *qp = (struct qux *)((char *)ip - offsetof(struct qux, b));
    global_ptr = &qp->c;
    printf("%d %d\n", qp->a, qp->huge[1234]);
}

void bar(void) {
    *global_ptr = 37;
}
```

I believe such code would be well-defined; `foo` must print out `1 0` and `fum` must return 38.  Of course, the programmer needs to ensure that `foo` is only ever called with the address of the `b` member of a `struct qux`, and that `bar()` isn't called again after `fum` returns, because of the dangling pointer - but if they do so then the code should work.

On the other hand, if you change the call in `fum` to `foo(NULL)`, you can see that everything vanishes: `s.huge` is never initialized nor even allocated, `s.b` disappears entirely, `s.a` and `s.c` are optimized away, and `return s.a+s.c;` is constant-folded into `return 5;`.  In this case the compiler can be sure that the struct never "escapes" and so it can be optimized as it pleases.